# "Partial" graph layout (with a fixed core)?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

Is there a way to apply a graph lay out algorithm to a `Graph` object in such a way that a subset of its vertices and a subset of its edges are fixed beforehand, and their positions/shapes remain unaffected by the algorithm?

Comment: Could you come up with an example of a `Graph` and the output you would expect?

Comment: igraph's DrL layout generator has this feature and I'm working on an [igraph interface](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) for Mathematica. However, I did not yet expose this option because I got very disappointed with the results I got from DrL.  I could never get it to look good on fairly simple graphs.